# OR logic with Django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm using [Django-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to allow the user to filter a database based on multiple choices in two fields. The filterset.py looks like this:

```
class TapFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
bar__region = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=CHOICES, label="Regions:", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,help_text="")
bar = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Bar.objects.all(), label="Bars:", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,help_text="")
```

However, this functions as an AND between the two lists. I need OR instead. That is, I need to show anything matching the selection in either category.

I have seen similar questions using normal filters, but I would prefer to keep using django-filter if possible.

The website in question is here: http://bestap.pythonanywhere.com/

Update: I've put this in my filtersets.py, but am clearly not doing things right...

```
class TapFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    bar__region = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=CHOICES, label="Regions:", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,help_text="")
    bar = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Bar.objects.all(), label="Bars:", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,help_text="")
    def qs(self):
        base_qs = Bar.objects.all()
        qs = Bar.objects.none()
        for name, filter_ in six.iteritems(self.filters):
            value = self.form.cleaned_data[name]
            qs = qs | filter_.filter(base_qs, value)
        return qs
```

This gives me the error 'function' object has no attribute 'count'.

Comment: You will need to most more details like how you are trying to use this filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to override `qs` on your `TapFilter` `FilterSet` subclass.

The [base implementation is not *that* complicated](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/develop/django_filters/filterset.py#L309-L361); the [essence of it loops over the filters applying them to the queryset](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/develop/django_filters/filterset.py#L323-L340).

Simplified:

```
for name, filter_ in six.iteritems(self.filters):
    value = self.form.cleaned_data[name]
    qs = filter_.filter(qs, value)
```

You need the union of the filters' QuerySets, which you can get because [`QuerySet` implements `__or__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L312-L321), so (again simplified) you'll need something like:

```
base_qs = Bar.objects.all()
qs = Bar.objects.none()
for name, filter_ in six.iteritems(self.filters):
    value = self.form.cleaned_data[name]
    qs = qs | filter_.filter(base_qs, value)
```

Hopefully that gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for your help! What is the qs = Bar.objects.empty() line intended to achieve? I get AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'empty.'

Comment: Oops. It should be `none` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#none

Comment: I feel a bit obtuse, but unsure exactly how to apply this. Have updated above with current attempt.